# AWS DynamoDB Object Mapper crashing with SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to build an iPhone app with swift, I've installed all the dependencies on "connect to your back-end" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html , I even have the amazon aws login page so it's def connected, just whenenver I add this line: 
  let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default() 
that it tells me to do in the tutorial, the app crashes on the screen that code is associated to with Thread 1: SIGABRT. Here's my code on the screen it's on.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import AWSCore  
import AWSAuthUI
import AWSMobileClient
import AWSUserPoolsSignIn
import AWSDynamoDB


class SampleViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        if !AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn {
            presentAuthUIViewController()
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        }

    }

    @IBAction func askPermission(_ sender: UIButton) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }







    func presentAuthUIViewController() {
        let config = AWSAuthUIConfiguration()
        config.enableUserPoolsUI = true

        AWSAuthUIViewController.presentViewController(
            with: self.navigationController!,
            configuration: config, completionHandler: { (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    // SignIn succeeded.
                } else {
                    // end user faced error while loggin in, take any required action here.
                }
        })

    }

}
```

I'd appreciate any help, and can post more information if needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have awsconfiguration.json file added to your app target? What version of SDK are you using? Can you post the exception message completely and the associated stacktrace?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Yes, the JSON file is attached, I used and configured it successfully before for other AWS back-end features. The SDK version of awsdynamoDB I am using is 2.6.18 [Image](http://prntscr.com/juk8i4) . And here is the whole stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/dbJ8jpLT Also here is an image of the screen it's crashing to, may also help. [image](http://prntscr.com/juk9zw)

Comment: @noahlattari  From your stacktrace, it appears that the SDK is unable to find the awsconfiguration.json file. Follow the steps listed here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#add-aws-mobile-sdk-basic-setup to resolve the issue.

Comment: That was the original tutorial i followed, and it doesn't really make sense that it couldn't find the SDK because the other SDK's can find the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following to the awsconfiguration.json after the section that defines "DynamoDBObjectMapper". Replace the 'YourRegion' placeholder below with the region where your Database is located. This is a required section in the awsconfiguration.json file and there may be in a bug in the tool that generates the config.

```
"DynamoDB": {
   "Default": {
   "Region": "YourRegion"
   }
},
```